# Vertex snapping with edge slide?

Tags: edges

Is this possible or something we're all waiting on?

When I go to slide a vertex along an edge (G,G) I can't snap it to another vertex along that line (from a different mesh).

[image: Vertex sliding-snapping issue]

-James F

Comment: I don't think it is possible as of yet, also this question was already asked.

Comment: Woops my mistake.

Waiting time I guess!

Cheers

Comment: @NoviceInDisguisecan you point to the duplicate?

Comment: @cegaton I am going to have to search a bit, it was a while ago

Answer (score 3):

A solution is:

1. Select the edge you want your vertex to slide and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad7</kbd> to snap view to selected;
2. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to create new transform orientation;
3. Choose it from available transform orientations in the 3d Viewport header (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) Optionally give it a meaningful name chck USE VIEW;
4. Move the vertex with <kbd>G</kbd> using the new transform orientation instead of Local or Global etc. Snap will work as usual.

[image]

Comment: It is needed to use the option "use view" in the tool option

Comment: What is "option Use View"? What is "tool option"? Can you use Blender interface terms to describe how to use it? As a side note if creating custom transform orientation you do *not* have to select it from transform orientations list. It will be selected for you.

Comment: @MrZak have you ever used the "Create Orientation"?
"Use View" is the first checkbox in the options (tool option is english, like: option "use View") and you don't need to select it from the orientation list only if the option: "Use after creation is checked".

Comment: Have you ever studied Blender interface terms? Finally it's now more clear what were you talking about. "Tool option" is NOT "tool option", it's Toolshelf. As these options on the Toolshelf are accessible only after creating Custom Transform Orientation they are avialble only in the Last Operator panel on the Toolshelf. A screenshot is indeed best here as you don't seem to explain well.

Comment: Late to reply but thanks @Zaldor !